# Aggregate multiple columns and rows into a json array

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I try to query multiple columns and rows from a table to create the xy-pairs for a step-linechart in json format.

I need the json like this:

```
[[63115200,213.4], [139769280,213.4], [139769280,213.39], 
[160911360,213.39], [160911360,215.1], [163853812,215.1]]
```

What I currently get is this:

```
[[[63115200,213.4], [139769280,213.4]], [[139769280,213.39],
[160911360,213.39]], [[160911360,215.1], [163853812,215.1]]]
```

I need to get rid of the square brackets json_build_array creates.

The table looks like this:

| bname | bfrom | bto | bval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EU | 63115200 | 139769280 | 213.4 |
| EU | 139769280 | 160911360 | 213.39 |
| EU | 160911360 | 163853812 | 215.1 |

My query looks currently like this:

```
SELECT   json_agg(json_build_array(array[bfrom,bval], array[bto,bval]) 
         ORDER BY bfrom asc) AS data
FROM     stepchart 
GROUP BY bname ORDER BY bname;
```

I've been struggling with this for the last hours but still have no clue how to do this.

I created a db-fiddle:
[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=168c9d68afc49c345d0dbac28cd670f3)

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: sorry for the table design. In preview it works.

Comment: your fiddle differs from the data you show here.

Answer (score 1):

```
select json_agg(u.a) from (
  select
    bname, bfrom, json_build_array(bfrom,bval) a
    FROM   stepchart 
  union all
  select
    bname, bfrom, json_build_array(bto,bval)
    FROM   stepchart 
  order by bname, bfrom
) u;
```

see [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1991623d96797ad5738a7f18481c9410)

```
[[63115200, 213.4], [139769280, 213.4], [139769280, 213.39], [160911360, 213.39], [160911360, -9999.9], [163853812, -9999.9]]
```